# Refer to an extern crate in macro expansion

Tags: rust, macros, alloc

I'm trying to write some macros that work in nostd environment as well as in std environment. In order to do so I have this kind of code in proc macro crate:

```
#[cfg(not(feature = "alloc"))]
{
    quote!(err.message = Some(::std::borrow::Cow::from(#m));)
}
#[cfg(feature = "alloc")]
{
    quote!(err.message = Some(::alloc::borrow::Cow::from(#m));)
}
```

This correctly produces the code that uses alloc when alloc feature is enabled, but the compiler complains

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `alloc` in the list of imported crates
```

Of course the reason is that the macro expansion is missing

```
extern crate alloc;
```

But adding that is a problem. Since it's a procedural derive macro, the extern crate will be added on each derive call. How can I refer to an extern crate in macro expansion? Using `$crate` does not seem to work inside `quote!`.

Comment: What is the problem with adding that to every expansion?

Comment: error[E0259]: the name `alloc` is defined multiple times

Comment: If you wrap every expansion in a block, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the expansion in a block, then you can define `alloc` multiple times.

Another common practice for proc macros that need auxiliary types is to create a crate that provides them, and reexport the macro from it. E.g. create `mycrate` and `mycrate-macros`. Then you can get rid of the whole `alloc` feature if you only need `alloc`-accessible types, like:

```rust
#![no_std]

extern crate alloc;

#[doc(inline)]
pub use mycrate_macros::my_macro;

#[doc(hidden)]
pub use alloc:borrow::Cow;
```

Then in the macro refer to `::my_crate::Cow`.